Convexity of cross entropy of two Gaussians with respect to the covariance matrix
Consider two multivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$. The cross-entropy can be written as $-\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)}[\mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)]=\frac{1}{2}\log\text{det}(\Sigma_2)+\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left(\Sigma_2^{-1}(\Sigma_1+\mu\mu^\top)\right)+C$ where $C$ collects terms without $\Sigma_2$ and $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$. I am wondering can the cross-entropy be convex or concave with respect to $\Sigma_2$? Because by letting the derivative, $\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}_2-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}_2((\Sigma_1+\mu\mu^\top))\Sigma^{-1}_2$, equal zero we can easily get a solution $\Sigma_2=(\Sigma_1+\mu\mu^\top)$. I'm curious would it be a maximum, minimum, or stationary point? The convexity or concavity seems to be helpful.
